# Calculated value column depends on another column

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How to get today's modified date in calculated column when someone selects `Done` in another list choice column.

The list has some values like as `Not Started, In Progress, Done`

Comment: You have two list, one list contains calculated column and other list contains choice column. m I right

Comment: You can use this formula to get modified date for item only if Status is Done 
Stats is Choice Column 
=IF(Status="Done",Modified,"Nothing")

Comment: Here is syntax for calculated column IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is syntax for calculated column If condition**

```
IF(logical_test,value_if_true,value_if_false)
```

Example

```
IF(Status="Done",Modified,"Nothing")
```

In above example **Status** is Choice Column

If status is Done then only it get modified column value